# ffmpeg livestream by ip camera with a problem of DTS

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, youtube

I'm a problem with a code of ffmpeg: `ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://admin:passw@xxxxxxxx.ddns.net:554/live/ch0" -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset medium -s 1920x1080 -b:v 5000k -acodec aac -strict -2 -ar 44100 -threads 6 -qscale 3 -b:a 712000 -bufsize 128k -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key"`

It's used for a live streaming by a ip camera, but I have this problem

```
[flv @ 0x558333a41100] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 73709, current: 73220; changing to 73709. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[aac @ 0x558333a0f100] Queue input is backward in time14.43 bitrate=1288.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.486x
[flv @ 0x558333a41100] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 74591, current: 73614; changing to 74591. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Especially in live streams, there will occasionally happen some "jumps" on timestamps. Why this happens... well, there are many reasons, including packet losses.
When this happens this will cause momentary distortion in the output.
Here FFmpeg tells you a jump has occurred. I consider this not an error on your side—just a warning.
As the warning says, FFmpeg already handled it (by correcting the timestamps).

There isn't anything much to do, other than sometimes you may need to restart the FFmpeg, because of the unexpected changes on the stream.

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much.
I proceeded to change the code with a simpler one.`"ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ddns.net:554/live/ch0" -tune zerolatency -s 1920x1080  -vcodec libx264 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -preset ultrafast -g 50 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key"`
actually the problem was that the live of yt would end even if ffmper kept processing so suddenly. With the new code the terminal no longer gives the error but the problem persists